# python manage.py runserver identified 0 issues but there are errors

Tags: python, django, django-channels

python manage.py runserver was working fine until I started creating django channels when suddenly everything stopped. I've tried running other sites that worked fine but its still the same

C:\personal\website>python manage.py runserver

```
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x0000028159B61048>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 225, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 123, in inner_run
    self.check_migrations()
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 427, in check_migrations
    executor = MigrationExecutor(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS])
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 18, in __init__
    self.loader = MigrationLoader(self.connection)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\django\db\migrations\loader.py", line 49, in __init__
    self.build_graph()
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\django\db\migrations\loader.py", line 268, in build_graph
    raise exc
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\django\db\migrations\loader.py", line 242, in build_graph
    self.graph.validate_consistency()
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\django\db\migrations\graph.py", line 243, in validate_consistency
    [n.raise_error() for n in self.node_map.values() if isinstance(n, DummyNode)]
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\django\db\migrations\graph.py", line 243, in <listcomp>
    [n.raise_error() for n in self.node_map.values() if isinstance(n, DummyNode)]
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\django\db\migrations\graph.py", line 96, in raise_error
    raise NodeNotFoundError(self.error_message, self.key, origin=self.origin)
django.db.migrations.exceptions.NodeNotFoundError: Migration admin.0004_auto_20190704_0341 dependencies reference nonexistent parent node ('admin', '0003_logentry_add_action_flag_choices')
```

Comment: Apparently you removed a migration file, but another migration file had a dependency on that file.

Comment: yes how do I solve this? ive even tried running sites that had no problem but the same error persisits.

Comment: you can delete all the old migrated files and migrate again

Comment: how to solve? just add the old migration file back. Look in your git history for the commit that caused this and revert.

Comment: i've tried this ive even knoticed that when I create a new project python manage.py runserver still doesn't work..  is there a way also to run python manage.py runserver,